# OpenLayers in android 4.4.2 webview

Tags: openlayers-2

I want display an openlayers map with a kml in android webview.
I implement [this example](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/kml.html?mode=advanced).
This work on android 4.1 but not in 4.4.2.

Here is my code:

```
private WebView webview;

webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
                webview.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
                webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
                webview.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
                webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);

webview.loadUrl("http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/kml.html?mode=advanced");
```

The closest thing about OpenLayers not working on 4.4.2.
https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/3035